# Add more than one view in a tab

Tags: android, view, tabs

I am trying to add content in tab view using "setContent(...)" method

```
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");
    spec.setContent(R.id.radioGroup1);  
    spec.setContent(R.id.button1);
```

when i add more than one item in setContent(...) using different methods it only prefers the last one.
How can i add two view under a single tab, in this case- radioGroup1 as well as button1 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can not directly add more then one view but aleternative is you can add container view (e.g. linear layout) and inside container layout you can add as many views you want for sure

this is exactly what you want..[nice example of tab](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/107693/Tabbed-Applications-in-Android)

Answer (score 1):

You have to group the two views into a single one - for example a `LinearLayout`.

It is typical in Android, that when you do stuff in a callback from the system (like e.g. `onCreate` or `onButtonPressed`) that the effect only come active after the user code returns and that the last setting 'overrides' previous ones in the same callback, as you have seen.